# iOS Notification extension error without description

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios10, xcode8

After I integrated a notification extension using Xcode 8 and iOS10, I have the following error and I can't find a solution for this yet.

Basically I send a push notification with mutable-content, but the extensions is not loaded, I see the following error when the OS tries to use the extension. Apple is not providing any description about what is failing really.

Any help would be great, from someone having this feature working already.

```
Dec 31 21:00:00 iPhone SpringBoard(libextension.dylib)[51] <Notice>: calling plugIn beginUsing:
Dec 31 21:00:57 iPhone pkd[86] <Notice>: assigning plug-in com.test.app.NotificationWithAttachmentExtension(1.0) to plugin sandbox
Dec 31 21:03:57 iPhone pkd[86] <Notice>: enabling pid=51 for plug-in com.test.app.NotificationWithAttachmentExtension(1.0) 38BB5FF1-2597-42E0-B950-169DBFA80573 /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A8C47706-C0EC-4FB1-ABA7-0118372F6900/testapp.app/PlugIns/NotificationWithAttachmentExtension.appex
Dec 31 21:00:53 iPhone SpringBoard(PlugInKit)[51] <Notice>: plugin com.test.app.NotificationWithAttachmentExtension interrupted
Dec 31 21:03:56 iPhone SpringBoard(PlugInKit)[51] <Notice>: Hub connection error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.test.app.NotificationWithAttachmentExtension" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.test.app.NotificationWithAttachmentExtension}
Jun 29 13:33:36 iPhone SpringBoard(libextension.dylib)[51] <Notice>: PlugInKit error in beginUsing:
Jun 17 23:33:04 iPhone SpringBoard(libextension.dylib)[51] <Notice>: killing invalid plugIn
Dec 31 21:00:00 iPhone SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[51] <Error>: Extension error whilst trying to modify push notification F502-9B36: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.test.app.NotificationWithAttachmentExtension" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.test.app.NotificationWithAttachmentExtension}
Dec 31 21:00:00 iPhone SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[51] <Notice>: [com.test.app] Saving notification F502-9B36
Dec 31 21:00:00 iPhone SpringBoard(libextension.dylib)[51] <Notice>: completed calling plugIn beginUsing: for pid: 0
```